# How to using echo HTML::script in laravel 5.0 in Controller

Tags: html, laravel, ckeditor, laravel-facade

I need to use

```js
echo HTML::script('js/ckeditor/ckeditor.js');
```

in my controller and function, but error not found **HTML**

I am using larvel 5.0.
tnx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HTML` and `FORM` are removed from Laravel 5+ to use them you have to include them in `composer.json`. And add an `Alias` and `Service Provider` in `config\app.php`
You can find them [here](https://packagist.org/packages/illuminate/html)

And as from laravel 5 `{{}}` is same as `{{e('sting')}}` `//htmlentities`
To output html you need to use `{!! HTML::() !!}` `without htmlentities`

And if you need to use `echo`
Simply wrap it to `<?php ?>` tags `<?php echo HTML::() ?>`

And if you use it Controller
you need to use like `\Html::()` or before `Controller class` add
`use HTML;`

`HTML` or `Html` depends on you `Alias array` in `config\app.php`

composer.json

```
"illuminate/html": "^5.0",
```

Config/app.php Service Provider

```
'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',
```

Config/app.php aliases

```
'Form'      => 'Illuminate\Html\FormFacade',
'HTML'      => 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade',
```

Controller

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use HTML;
class SomeController extends Controller{
    public function foo(){
        echo HTML::();
    }
}
```

Comment: notice : my code works in View but does not work in controller.

Comment: Why you need it controller? HTML and FORM are made for view.
Paste the whole controller code please! Also check you `Alias` array in app.php you have it `HTML` or `html`

Comment: This is special situation because i wanna upload image via CKEDITOR and have to use it in my controller.

Comment: I Used Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade\HTML but does not worked.